# Target specific attributes with merge sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, mergesort

Implemented the merge sort algorithm in my javascript code.

I'm wonder how I can target specific attributes like `date`, `title`, `name` etc for sorting in an array when calling merge sort like `mergeSort(array);`.

```
function mergeSort(arr){
    var len = arr.length;
    if(len <2)
        return arr;
    var mid = Math.floor(len/2),
        left = arr.slice(0,mid),
        right =arr.slice(mid);

    return merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right){
    var result = [],
        lLen = left.length,
        rLen = right.length,
        l = 0,
        r = 0;
    while(l < lLen && r < rLen){
        if(left[l] < right[r]){
            result.push(left[l++]);
        }
        else{
            result.push(right[r++]);
        }
    }  

    return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}
```

Using it in a sort options method. What I want is to print a sorted list. The way the list is sorted will be defined by the users chosen sort option.

```
function sortConfig(array, sortOption){
 if(sortOption == 'title') mergeSort(array.Title);
 //..etc
}
```

Comment: Hummm... What? Show us how you use this function

Comment: You don't really want to rewrite your mergeSort function each time you specify another attribute to sort by. Rather use a comparison callback equivalent to the native `sort` function.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but those are for a reason. We don't know what's `sortConfig` is, nor `array` - Don't just show us your function, show us the parameters - What is the expected results vs. the actual, show us how you call those functions - Just add more context

Comment: @le_m Could you give an example?

Comment: You could add a functional argument to your merge sort that returns the property you wish to use  like `(item) => item.title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the behavior with an optional argument, you could do it in the following way:

```
function mergeSort(arr, compare = (item => item))
```

This would set compare function to be the item itself when running the merge

and then we update the calling of the merge and mergeSort itself, where they now all get the compare argument

```
return merge(mergeSort(left, compare), mergeSort(right, compare), compare);
```

and ofcourse the declaration for your merge function itself

```
function merge(left, right, compare)
```

Which then calls the compare function upon comparison, like here:

```
if (compare(left[l]) < compare(right[r]))
```

This lets you choose wether you wish to give an argument or not wen you call your mergeSort function, like:

```
console.log(mergeSort(nrs).join(','));
console.log(mergeSort(nrs, n => -n).join(','));

console.log(mergeSort(arr, i => i.id));
console.log(mergeSort(arr, i => i.title));
```

```js
function mergeSort(arr, compare = (item => item)) {
  var len = arr.length;
  if (len < 2)
    return arr;
  var mid = Math.floor(len / 2),
    left = arr.slice(0, mid),
    right = arr.slice(mid);

  return merge(mergeSort(left, compare), mergeSort(right, compare), compare);
}

function merge(left, right, compare) {
  var result = [],
    lLen = left.length,
    rLen = right.length,
    l = 0,
    r = 0;
  while (l < lLen && r < rLen) {
    if (compare(left[l]) < compare(right[r])) {
      result.push(left[l++]);
    } else {
      result.push(right[r++]);
    }
  }

  return result.concat(left.slice(l)).concat(right.slice(r));
}
var arr = [{
  title: 'test 5',
  id: 4
}, {
  title: 'test',
  id: 0
}, {
  title: 'test 3',
  id: 2
}, {
  title: 'test 4',
  id: 3
}];
var nrs = [5, 3, 7, 156, 15, 6, 17, 9];

// and call like
console.log(mergeSort(nrs).join(','));
console.log(mergeSort(nrs, n => -n).join(','));

// or like
console.log(mergeSort(arr, i => i.id));
console.log(mergeSort(arr, i => i.title));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of brevity, these examples show how to sort an array of objects based on a property with a string value. You would most likely need to create some additional logic to handle different types of properties.

**1. Array.sort()**

You can do this with the Array.sort() method

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jbird/8ssn5po9/)

```
myThings = [
  { alpha: 'a' },
  { alpha: 'x' },
  { alpha: 'p' },
  { alpha: 'orange' },
  { alpha: 'c' },
  { alpha: 'w' }
];

myThings.sort(function(a, b) {
  var alphaA = a.alpha.toUpperCase();
  var alphaB = b.alpha.toUpperCase();
  if (alphaA < alphaB) return -1;
  if (alphaA > alphaB) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(myThings);
```

**2. Or, compare array item property value instead of array item value**

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jbird/kteb46ua/)

```
function mergeSort(arr, prop) {
    if (arr.length < 2)
        return arr;

    var middle = parseInt(arr.length / 2);
    var left   = arr.slice(0, middle);
    var right  = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);

    return merge(mergeSort(left, prop), mergeSort(right, prop), prop);
}

function merge(left, right, prop) {
    var result = [];

    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left[0][prop] <= right[0][prop]) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    while (left.length)
        result.push(left.shift());

    while (right.length)
        result.push(right.shift());

    return result;
}

myThings = [
  { alpha: 'a' },
  { alpha: 'x' },
  { alpha: 'p' },
  { alpha: 'orange' },
  { alpha: 'c' },
  { alpha: 'w' }
];

console.log(mergeSort(myThings, 'alpha'));
```